# How Can I Prevent make-process from failing if the default-directory doesn't exist?

Tags: process, error-handling

Usually, when you open a file, Emacs prompts you to `run M-x make-directory RET RET` if the directory doesn't exist.

However, after writing my own advice, I realized that opening files in directories that don't exist was giving me a lot of errors. After digging a bit, I found that apparently `make-process` tries to set the current directory to the buffer's `default-directory`. Since it doesn't exist yet, it fails with an error saying that setting the directory didn't work.

Is there a way to prevent this, and still have the `make-process` command work? I looked at the keyword arguments, but I couldn't find any that would prevent the working directory from being set.

Comment: If you can control the keyword arguments you can also wrap `make-process` into a `let`-form [binding `default-directory` locally](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html) to the name of an existing directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading in make-process comments about "current buffer's current directory", assume this is a bug. Can't see why a buffer connected to a process must have a file resp. filename. Seems worth a bug-report.

Comment: To make sure I explained this correctly, let me elaborate a bit. I meant that when you create a process with `make-process`, Emacs tries to set the working directory of the process to the default directory of the current buffer. I didn't mean that the buffer it creates (i.e. the `buffer` key in the arguments) has that set as its default directory. Reading your answer, I thought you might have thought I meant the second one, and not the first.

Comment: @ParhamDoustdar AFAIU make-process assumes an existing buffer-file-name leading to determine the current directory. But such assumption isn't justified when just creating a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution seems to be to simply wrap the `call-process` or `make-process` call with `with-existing-directory`.